# installing a bstfun function from GitHub on offline windows pc error had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, github, stat

I am installing a function from GitHub - ddsjoberg/bstfun: Miscellaneous collection of functions  on offline pc using following command. But I get an error of installation of package 'H:/bstfun-master/bstfun-master' had non-zero exit status

```
install.packages("H:\\bstfun-master\bstfun-master", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: The good stuff, perhaps indicating why a package failed to build/install is found by scrolling up from the final `non-zero exit status` to the first error, evaluating that (perhaps you need a/several pkg(s)) installed prior to the build, or a library (though not indicated in this case). HTH

Comment: @ Chris. thanks let me have a look.

Comment: @Chris thanks there were dependencies missing which installed. but now i got ``` Error: Package ‘gtsummary’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please reinstall it 
Execution halted
Error: lazy loading failed for package ‘bstfun’

Installation of package ‘H:/bstfun-master’ had non-zero exit status
```   I uninstalled the gtsummary’ and tried to run but then I got an error of gtsummary package missing. So  I installed gtsummary again and rerun the code but again same error

Comment: check that you have `broom, gt, and labeled` pkgs as these are required for `gtsummary`. If you don't have a lot of pkgs yet, you probably want to always use `install.packages('some_pkg', dependencies = TRUE)`, you can use `packageVersion('some_pkg)` to see if you have it already.

Comment: thanks @Chris. i sorted this out.